# User's reviews or ratings to OpenStreetMap objects?

Tags: google-places-api, openstreetmap, rating, review

I have downloaded an [OpenStreetMap data](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/). This data contain useful information like spatial coordinates and the textual description of many objects. For example, the hotel Park Hyatt at coordinates (25.2435938, 55.3328381) is a spatial object stored in OpenStreetMap dataset.

I have to associate the spatial object (i.e. Park Hyatt) to a user review. It can be a user evaluation (i.e. "good" or "bad") or a user rating (like 5/10).

So, I am looking for a public dataset with user reviews/ratings of places stored in OpenStreetMap.

Until now, I have found the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/). I can solve my problem using it, but it has access limits. I will need some time to obtain all ratings I need. So, I am wondering if already exists any dataset with user ratings to OpenStreetMap Objects.

Comment: I don't think such a mapping exists yet. Did you check Google's terms of service if you are allowed to combine their data with other data and if you are allowed to publish it afterwards?

Comment: You are right. The term 10.4.c.ii states: "No creation or augmentation of data sets based on Google’s Content or Services.". I should not publish this dataset. Thanks for your advice.